# Laravel 5.1 belongs to many not working

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have following tables.

### Users

id

name

### Events

id

name

### Cards

id

name

### Transfers

id

event_id

card_id

I added the belongs to relationship in the Card.php as well as in Event.php

```
class Card extends Model
{
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

     public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class,'transfers');
    }


}

class Event extends Model
{
        use SoftDeletes;

        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function cards()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Card::class,'transfers');
    }





}
```

I was trying to use the following statements in my controller both of them returned error

```
> echo count($user->events->cards->where([['id', '=',
> '57']])->find());die; //$cards is not defined.


> echo count($user->events->cards()->where([['id', '=',
> '57']])->find());die; // method cards() is not defined.I tried this after reading a tutorial
```

Any help on resolving this issue is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If a user can own many events, the method `->cards()` doesn't make sense on a collection. You're also not associating the event with a user via a foreign key.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks. I have the following piece of code in the User class.  public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life a lot easier by using the [`hadManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship:

```
class User extends Model {
     public function cards() {
          return $this->hasManyThrough(Card::class, Event::class);
     }    
}
```

Then in principle you can do something like :

```
$user->cards()->where(['id', '=', '57']);
```